# System refuses to boot at the first attempt

Tags: grub2

everyone. After the upgrade to natty my system started to refuse booting at the first attempt. More details: on the grub menu i'm trying to start ubuntu and this causes errors:

```
error: file not found
error: you need to load the kernel first
push any key to proceed
```

Then grub menu shows up again. After some attempts to start the error messages don't appear and system boots up normally. That happens every time.

*fdisk -l* output:

```
/dev/sda1   *           1       10199    81922016+   7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda2           10199       30402   162276352    f  W95 extended (LBA)
/dev/sda5           10200       10759     4498168+  82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6           15623       30402   118714368   83  Linux
/dev/sda7           10760       14771    32225280   83  Linux
/dev/sda8           14772       15622     6834176   83  Linux
```

The / directory (*/dev/sda7*) is formatted as reiserfs. Any idea how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reiserfs support in grub does not get much testing as Reiserfs usage has been declining. GRUB 1.99 rc1 (shipped in Ubuntu 11.04) contains some Reiserfs fixes, though I don't think that the bug fixed would present itself with your precise symptoms. Please try upgrading to grub 1.99 rc1 or newer and if you can still reproduce the problem please file a bug report.

That said though, I'd recommend going with ext{3,4} for production systems as it's just better supported in general.